# How can Google(gmail) know the flight details before departure

Tags: gmail

Recently I booked one flight from A --> B ---> C. On the day before departure,  I checked with Gmail and it reminded me that the flight from A to B will be delayed for about two hours. Then I got a message from the air company to tell me that they have changed my flight from B to C into another one which is almost two hours later than my original one. It seems Google already knew my 1st flight will be delayed even before the airline company.

I'm curious what's the channel for Google to get the information? I checked with flightaware and nothing about the delay of my flight.

Comment: I wouldn't say google knew about it before the airline, they just notified you first.  Most likely Google has a data feed from the various airlines for this data, but I think this question is probably off-topic for SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programing related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google gets a lot of data from several channels. To name a few:

- gmail
- adsense
- google crawler
- google+
- google chrome
- google maps

Naturally there are many projects not mentioned here, developed or owned by Google. Since Google is one of the biggest companies in the IT sector, it is no wonder that their database gathered the data earlier than your notification was sent.

From your case one cannot say that Google new about the information earlier, the only thing we know is that they have sent you the notification earlier. It is quite possible that one of the employees of the flight company uses gmail. If so, then his/her mails arrive to Google's server and some automatic analyzers parse the data and then trigger the notification event. If the company was still discussing how they should communicate the delay on gmail, in the meantime Google was analyzing the gathered data and as a result sent you the notification.

You will never know the exact details unless you will start to work for Google, since Google employees will not disclose the inner information of the company to outsiders, outsiders do not have the given information. We can only guess, but we can more-or-less know that the data was gathered by Google.

Answer (score 0):

Events from Gmail
When you get an email about an event like a flight, concert, or restaurant reservation, it's added to your calendar automatically. If you don't want events from Gmail on your calendar, you can delete a single event, or change your settings so that events aren't added automatically.

Note: Events from Gmail aren't available for Government accounts, accounts with data location restrictions, or Google Accounts that don't have Gmail.